# Spring boot actuator secure services does not work fine

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I an Trying to secure spring actuator services /manage context path when calling for example:

http://localhost:9091/manage/metrics

with this config in my yalm.properties

`management:
     port: 9091
     address: 127.0.0.1
     context-path: /manage
     security: 
            enabled: true
             role: ADMIN`.

[Git branch with security actuator service layer](https://github.com/cristianprofile/spring-boot-mvc-complete-example/pull/1)

but access to every service is still free.

Spring security config:

'@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

```
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/pizzas","/info","/addPizza").hasAnyRole("USER","ADMIN").and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/users","/addUser").hasRole("ADMIN").and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/static/**","/logout","/login").permitAll();

    http.formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error").permitAll();

    http.logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/?logout").deleteCookies("remember-me").permitAll();


    http.sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1).
    expiredUrl("/?expired").maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true).and()
    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED);
}

/**
 * Configure global security with Bccyptenoncder and custom userDetailService with Spring Security
 * @param auth
 * @throws Exception
 */
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsServiceImpl).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}


/**
 * Bcrypt password encoding configuration, more info at http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-registration-password-encoding-bcrypt
 * @return
 */
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
'
```

Comment: I updated project.It works fine, but when i access to an endpoint app redirect my http request to manage/login which it does not exist obviously because my app with context path /pizza has the login. Which is the way to redirect to custom login in actuator endpoints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Spring boot team has resolved me this issue. I  share the solution here:**

**Same Origin Policy**

You cannot use the login page from your main Spring Application within actuator security. The reason is that the cookie is going to be associated with the domain + port + context path of the application. This is part of the Same Origin Policy

This means if you sent the user to localhost:9090/pizza/login and authenticated, when you visited localhost:9091/manage/ the JSESSIONID cookie would not be submitted to the management application which means you would not be seen as authenticated.

In order to authenticate across domains (i.e. different ports in this case) you would need some single sign on (OpenID, CAS, SAML, etc) mechanism.

**Mapping a Login Page in the Management Application**

In order to use this configuration you would need to setup a login page within the management application. To do this you would just need to return an HTML form when /login is requested. However, I'm not really certain how you would do that within the Boot management application. Perhaps @philwebb or @dsyer can elaborate on how one would do that.

**Distinct Security Configuration for the Management Application**

Alternatively you could create separate security configuration for the management application that allows authenticating with Basic Authentication. To do this you would create another Security Configuration that looks something like this:

```
@Order(0)
@Configuration
public class ManagementSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         http
            .requestMatchers()
                .requestMatchers(request -> "/manage".equals(request.getContextPath()))
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and()
            .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

This would make sure that if the context root is "/manage" that this security configuration is used. A few points of interest:

@Order(0) makes sure the configuration occurs before your other security configuration since by default any subclass of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter will be ordered at 100. This is important because only the first WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is used (similar to the authorizeRequests() matchers).
The request matcher is using a lambda for matching on the contextPath. I had thought there was a better way to distinguish Spring Boot application from the main application, but it does not appear that is the case. Perhaps @dsyer knows how this should be done.
NOTE

You can rewrite your configuration much more concisely as:

```
 http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/pizzas","/info","/addPizza").hasAnyRole("USER","ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/users","/addUser").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/static/**","/logout","/login").permitAll()
        .and()
    .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .failureUrl("/login?error")
        .permitAll()
        .and()
    .logout()
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/?logout")
        .deleteCookies("remember-me")
        .permitAll();
```

You might consider reading Spring Security Java Config Preview: Readability for details on how to format the configuration to better read it too.